# NestJS Controller for @Get(':key') gets directed to @Get() when key param is empty

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

For my NestJS code, I am writing the controller `@Controller('testapp/testroute')`. I would like to have both `@Get()` to get all of the data, and `@Get(':key')` to get a single document.
What I hope to achieve is that `@Get(':key')` errors when `key` is empty, i.e. when `http://testapp/testroute/` is called.
However, I realised that whenever `key` is empty, the API call is directed to `@Get()` controller instead, which is undesirable.
How do I differentiate these API calls?

PS: I have also attempted to add the following `class-validator` validation on the `key` param, but it still does not seem to differentiate the controllers.

```
export class KeyParamsDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  key: string;
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can do that. The @Get() controller is supposed to look for clean route with no params, and automatically if you dont have a param, the request will fall back to @Get() controller.
However, @Get(:params) is expecting a parameter here. If there was no default route, this would have still worked, but since there is, it would not work.

You can reproduce the same behavior in node as well. 

_In short,  this wont work. You have to either send some default param like 'empty' or change the default route to something else._

Comment: You can try using the @Get(:key) controller defined first and the @Get() defined later. And then inside @Get(:key) controller check if key is empty. That could work since express follows top bottom approach according to route specificity.

Comment: Hi @sanyaldip, thank you for your reply! I tried changing the order but it doesn't seem to work either D:

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Look at it from the perspective of the URL. You have the following

```
<host>/testapp/testroute
<host>/testapp/testroute/:key
```

Now when you send the request `GET <host>/testapp/testroute/` you should be hitting that first route, right? But you're also saying that you want to throw an error because there's no `:key` value, even though that URL doesn't match for the `/:key` path. If it were to, and you were to throw an error everytime there's no `:key`, you couldn't call to the base `GET` route, because it would match the `GET /:key` route. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yup this makes a lot of sense. I'm just confused, I was able to achieve this when using `@nestjs/core` & `@nestjs/common` v7.6.15 though. The issue I'm facing now it in v8.0.6. Could this be something that was introduced only in more recent version?